# Python built-in types subclassing

Tags: python, initialization, subclassing, built-in-types

What's wrong with this code?

```
class MyList(list):
  def __init__(self, li): self = li
```

When I create an instance of `MyList` with, for example, `MyList([1, 2, 3])`, and then I print this instance, all I get is an empty list `[]`. If `MyDict` is subclassing `list`, isn't `MyDict` a `list` itself?

NB: both in Python 2.x and 3.x.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You need to call the list initializer:

```
class MyList(list):
     def __init__(self, li):
         super(MyList, self).__init__(li)
```

Assigning to `self` in the function just replaces the local variable with the list, not assign anything to the instance:

```
>>> class MyList(list):
...      def __init__(self, li):
...          super(MyList, self).__init__(li)
... 
>>> ml = MyList([1, 2, 3])
>>> ml
[1, 2, 3]
>>> len(ml)
3
>>> type(ml)
<class '__main__.MyList'>
```

Comment: Would `list.__init__(self)` also work when inheriting from `list`?

Comment: @Wolf: yes, but that'd preclude multiple inheritance, e.g. using this class as a base together with another class. `list` might not be the next class in the MRO in such cases.

Comment: Thanks for pointing on that! The short answer I already found here: [*Subclassing Built-in Types*](http://www.cafepy.com/article/python_attributes_and_methods/ch03s02.html). *MRO* I hope I correctly resolved to *Method Resolution Order*.

Comment: @Wolf: yes, sorry. MRO stands for Method Resolution Order, the order in which base classes are searched to resolve a requested method.

Answer (score -1):

I figured it out on my own: `self` is an instance of a subclass of `list`, so it can't be casted to list still being a `MyList` object.

Comment: No, `self` is a reference to an instance of `MyList`. Python doesn't have casting. See Martijn Pieter's answer.

Comment: @chepner While technically true, it is very common even for people who understand the nitty-gritty of how names reference/point to objects and the effects for mutable vs unmutable types to express such a relationship as "x _is a_ list of three integers" even x was assigned as `a=7